# Difference CFAutoRoot vs CFRoot vs SuperUser vs Armeabi-universal?

Tags: rooting, superuser

What difference CFAutoRoot with CFRoot with eu.chainfire.superuser with android-armeabi-universal-root-signed?

I'm still a little bit confused. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Superuser application is to manage root that is already available from su binary.

CFAutoRoot is to exploit a security flaw to install said binaries and patch boot image to load said binaries with proper privileges during boot.